# C# LINQ create month and year list

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have a collection of flyers with a property `FlyerDate` as datetime and I want to create a dropdown list with month and year, such "nov 2015, dec 2015, jan 2016"...

This is my code:

```
var monthList = flyers.Where(i => i.FlyerDate != DateTime.MinValue && i.FlyerDate.Year >= 2013)
    .GroupBy(i => i.FlyerDate.Month)
    .Select(g => new { 
        Month = g.Key, 
        Year = g.First(i => i.FlyerDate != DateTime.MinValue).FlyerDate.Year, 
        FullDate = String.Concat(DateTimeFormatInfo.CurrentInfo.GetMonthName(g.Key), " ", g.First(i => i.FlyerDate != DateTime.MinValue).FlyerDate.Year), 
        Total = g.Count(i => i.FlyerID > 0) 
    }
);
```

I would that the `GroupBy` works both on month and year as in my case the list contains only the first occurrence of each months. Any hints?

Comment: `i.FlyerDate != DateTime.MinValue` is not needed due to the second condition

Comment: `.GroupBy(i => i.FlyerDate.Month * 10000 + i.FlyerDate.Year)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to group by an anonymous type containing both, the year and the month:

```
var monthList = flyers.Where(i => i.FlyerDate.Year >= 2013)
    .GroupBy(i => new { i.FlyerDate.Year, i.FlyerDate.Month })
    .Select(g => new { 
        Year  = g.Key.Year,
        Month = g.Key.Month, 
        FullDate = DateTimeFormatInfo.CurrentInfo.GetMonthName(g.Key.Month) + " " + g.Key.Year
    });
```

Btw, if you want the abbreviated month-name as your desired result suggests you need to use `DateTimeFormatInfo.CurrentInfo.GetAbbreviatedMonthName` instead of `GetMonthName`.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect your issue may be the `GroupBy(i => i.FlyerDate.Month)` clause. That grouping doesn't appear to respect year, so you'd be left with only 12 groups by the time you make it to your `Select`.

Incorporating the year into that `GroupBy` lambda could create a unique group for each month. Assuming your `Month` and `Year` are `int`s:

```
.GroupBy(i => (i.FlyerDate.Year * 12) + i.FlyerDate.Month)
```

might be a good place to start.

Answer (score 0):

```
var query = flyers.GroupBy(f => f.FlyerDate.ToString("MMM yyyy"))

foreach (var group in query)
{
    Console.WriteLine(group.Key);
    foreach (Flyer f in group)
        Console.WriteLine(f.FlyerDate);
}
```